# Is the repositories list being maintained?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be a little bit of duplication between the [repositories](http://ros.org/wiki/Repositories) list that is manually created, and the [packages](http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php?package_type=package&distro=groovy) list which I believe is automatically generated from the [rosdoc/hydro/doc.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/doc.yaml) (etc) file. Am I right and do we still need this repositories list?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66152/is-the-repositories-list-being-maintained?/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The list is not being maintained and should probably be removed to avoid out of date information.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-07-10**:
I have removed most of that page's references and added a warning at the top of the page